# Перехватчик http-запросов

Tags: android, retrofit2

Я создала класс `CookieInterceptor`, который извлекает cookie из первого ответа сервера и добавляет их для всех последующих запросов телефона:

```
public class CookieInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "TAG",
            SET_COOKIE_TAG = "Set-Cookie",
            COOKIE_TAG = "Cookie",
            SESSION_ID_NAME = "JSESSIONID=";

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        request = processRequest(request);
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);

        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "header size: " + request.headers().size());

        for (String name : request.headers().names()) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "header name: " + name + ", value: " + request.headers().get(name));
        }

        response = processResponse(response);
        return response;
    }

    //Extract cookies from the first server response
    private Response processResponse(Response response) {
        if (response.header(SET_COOKIE_TAG) != null) {
            final List<String> cookieHeaders = response.headers(SET_COOKIE_TAG);
            for (String cookieHeader : cookieHeaders) {
                if (cookieHeader.contains(SESSION_ID_NAME)) {
                    String sessionId = cookieHeader.substring(11, cookieHeader.indexOf(';'));
                    App.setSessionId(sessionId);
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "extacted cookie: " + SESSION_ID_NAME + sessionId);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    //Add cookies for all subsequent requests
    private Request processRequest(Request request) {
        if(!request.url().toString().equals(App.getFirstUrl())) {
            if (App.getSessionId() != null) {
                request = request.newBuilder()
                        .addHeader(COOKIE_TAG, App.getSessionId())
                        .build();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "added cookie: " + SESSION_ID_NAME + App.getSessionId());
            }
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

В итоге в логах я вижу следующее.

Первый запрос от телефона:

```
--> POST http://host:8081/read
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 17
{"id":"FAE13980"}
--> END POST (28-byte body)
```

Первый ответ от сервера, куки с идентификатором сессии получены:

```
header size: 0
extacted cookie: JSESSIONID=A2B41558168583E9A30797228D0371FE
<-- 200 http://host:8081/read (321ms)
...
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=A2B41558168583E9A30797228D0371FE; Path=/; HttpOnly
...
<-- END HTTP (119-byte body)
```

Второй запрос от телефона:

```
--> POST http://host:8081/auth
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 36
{"id":"FAE13980","commandRs":["40"]}
--> END POST (79-byte body)
added cookie: JSESSIONID=A2B41558168583E9A30797228D0371FE
header size: 1
header name: Cookie, value: A2B41558168583E9A30797228D0371FE
```

По логам похоже, что идентификатор сессии добавляется к header-у запроса уже после того, как запрос был послан... Как это можно исправить?

P.S.: Для логирования я использую `okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor`. Или же это HttpLoggingInterceptor неправильно логирует header-ы запроса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина неверного логирования была в том, что я добавила interceptor-ы в неверной последовательности:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logInterceptor)
                .addInterceptor(new CookieInterceptor())
```

Получается, HttpLoggingInterceptor сначала логировал header-ы запроса, а потом CookieInterceptor добавлял ещё один header, естественно, он не выводился.
После изменения порядка следования interceptor-ов:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new CookieInterceptor()) 
                .addInterceptor(logInterceptor)
```

логи стали выводиться правильно:

```
added cookie: JSESSIONID=76225B5853448735A6F275C1A994E609
--> POST http://host:8081/auth
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 79
Cookie: 76225B5853448735A6F275C1A994E609
```